# How does agro work in The Elder Scrolls Online?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

From a tank perspective, how does the agro system work in ESO?
I only see a very limited amount of abilities that will force a target to attack you for *x* seconds (and this is only inside the **one hand and shield** skills)

What if i want to be a mage tank with a spellwand or a 2handed tank? How can i effectively hold agro and ensure i take the most hits?

Does first hit count for more agro? Does higher dps mean higher agro? Is it proximity based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Higher DPS will mean more aggro, but you're typically not able to hold aggro by damage alone, since pure DPS characters will most likely outdamage you rather quickly.

If you don't want to resort to shields, you can use any other weapon in combination with **Inner Fire** and its morphs from the **Undaunted** guild skill line. This offers you a ranged cast taunt you can use with any weapon, just keep in mind it's quite expensive in comparison.

Due to this many tanks use a shield and one-handed weapon on their secondary weapon bar, even if they want to primarily use a two-handed weapon. It is possible to switch, taunt, switch back, and continue fighting, although this requires significantly more micro-management and you'll be losing some damage this way.